# UITableView - controls / IBActions embedded in custom UITableViewCell class

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to have a table with custom `UITableViewCell` class as rows. Within each row (custom `UITableViewCell`), I have a control which the user can use to change the state of something in that row.

Let's say for sake of an example that each table row (custom `UITableViewCell`) contains a button and a label, and I want the clicking of the button to change the label text from "activated" to "deactivated" back and forth.

*NOTE** I understand that for the above scenario I can use the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method to implement, but this doesn't work for my actual use scenario. I used the above scenario because its simpler, and includes the core functionality I need.

Normally if this were not in a `UITableViewCell`, I would have a button with an `IBAction` to the `UIViewController` custom class, and an `IBOutlet` to a label. The `IBAction` method would change the text of the `IBOutlet` label. Pretty standard stuff.

But with the control embedded in a table row, I cannot make `IBAction` connections. I've tried making `IBAction` connections to the `UIViewController` as well as the `UITableViewCell`, but it doesn't seem to allow it. How should I go about setting this up? It seems to me like a pretty useful thing to do in interface design, so I think it should be possible right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I can control-drag from the button in a UITableViewCell xib to my header files to create IBAction. You just choose connection from Outlet to Action.

On the other hand, you can specify your Button's action by code.

If you button is a property, let's say it's self.tableCellButton, add the action like:

```
[self.tableCellButton addTarget:self action:@selector(yourAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Thanks! for providing both an interface builder answer as well as a programmatic one. 

It turns out you were right; you can make IBAction connections. What I had to do though was open up the Assistant Editor, with the Storyboard and my custom UITableViewCell class side-by-side. Then I can drag from the UIControl in the Storyboard into my code and make an IBAction connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can set button's action in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like so :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! YourCustomCell

    cell.button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    return cell
}

func buttonClicked(button: UIButton) {
    // get row index
    let index = self.tableView.indexPathsForRowsInRect(button.superview!.convertRect(button.frame, toView: self.tableView))
}
```